# Android: download image from URL to Assets folder

Tags: android, image, download, assets

I have a method that downloads an image from a given URL. Is it posible to store the downloaded image in the Assets folder and then reference it at runtime?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The asset folder is not listed as a [storage option](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). You need to use the [internal storage or external storage API's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to store your image.

Answer (score 1):

There's no assets folder on your device,you can save your image to your own folder on sd card,with the proper android permission.